# XCode 4.5 auto generation of @synthesize

Tags: properties, build-automation, xcode4.5, synthesis, viewdidunload

I understand that in xcode 4.5 it auto generates @synthesize and also implements the underscore prefix best practice to the variable assignment (as mentioned in another thread).  I have TWO related question which your help will be greatly appreciated:

1. Is there documentation that describes these details about xcode 4.5? I don't see where it is immediately.  How do you find this out?
2. Also, it seems, when an IBOutlet is drag n dropped the usual 'viewDidUnload' implementation is no longer generated either where it was in xcode 4.4.  Should I implement that myself or there something going on that makes it no longer necessary?

Thanks!
Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6, the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods of UIViewController are now deprecated.

You can go to apples web site to looks at the Xcode 4.5 features

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_5.html

Comment: But where exactly?  I've searched and don't see explicit documentation to this effect (in xcode 4.5 features too).  Do you have a link?

**EDIT**: I already know of that link but it has very little info.  Am I missing something?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I found it.  here's the link:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166